# How to request price range from Yelp business API?

Tags: api, yelp

I want to request the price range of a business on YELP API, but I don't receive any price range in the json response. In documentation they say that it's include in the request, but in FAQ they say :
"Are business attributes such as hours and pricing available in the API?
Business attributes are not returned in Yelp API queries. For a full list of what information is available in API queries, please see the documentation section."
How can I do?

Comment: It seems like a deliberate decision from them not to include the price range in the API. Not sure you can go around that.